# Get the co-ordinates of the screen in android application

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an Android application and I need to handle various touch events.

Consider the following requirements:

- If the user touches on the right side of the screen I want to display next screen.
- If user touches on the left side of the screen I want to display previous screen.

On the whole I have about 25 screens.

How can I get the logical coordinates of the screen and trigger the required event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

```
     float x =event.getRawX();
     float y =event.getRawY();
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Note : `getX()` and `getY()`, returns the position(x,y) of touch in relation with the View, `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` returns the position ( x,y ) in relation of the screen of your Android phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method for getting screen X and Y coordinated:

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         float xcoordinated =event.getX();
         float ycoordinated =event.getY();
         return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: Yes that will definately help me, but how to know that the given x and y coordinates are on the left or right hand side of the screen.

Comment: I believe x=0,y=0 for top-left corner.

Comment: Ok getDevice height and width , ex- height=100 and width=100 if your xcoordinate value lessthen width/2 it is left other wise it is right same as for height